# Go RE2 regex repeating group with condition

Tags: regex, go, re2

I am using an RE2 expression to parse data that has several forms and pick out quad groups of 4 numbers. For example:

1. 1111.2222.3333.4444
2. 1111.2222,3333,4444
3. 1111 2222 3333 4444
4. 1111.2222 3333.4444
5. 1111 2222.3333 4444

Currently I use this: ([0-9]{4}[.,\s]){3}[0-9]{4}
which is absolutely fine and provides results. Now I have a requirement to refine the expression so that the first character used as the divider will be carried through to the rest of the match. So in the examples number 1 is divided by a dot throughout whereas number 2 is mixed. I need to only match those that have the same divider and not match those that do not.
The only way I got this to work is to use several expressions each to detect a single character like this example for dots: ([0-9]{4}[.]){3}[0-9]{4} or this one for commas ([0-9]{4}[,]){3}[0-9]{4}
Well they work well but I am sure there is a more elegant way of expressing this on one line.

I also tried ([0-9]{4}[.]){3}[0-9]{4}|([0-9]{4}[,]){3}[0-9]{4} which also works with the OR operator there but again seems inelegant. Am I chasing something that cannot be done on RE2?

(edit: should not type regex from memory without checking first!)

Comment: Right, backreferences are not supported in RE2. What you do right now is the only regex way.

Comment: ah ok many thanks Wiktor.